# Infinite loop problem

Tags: android, animation, loops

I am trying to get my animation to spin until the user clicks on the view. I have set the animation to spin once and I want it to keep going on some kind of loop instead of using .clearAnimation so that the animation doesnt just stop half way through a cycle when clicked. The code I have come up with so obviously won't work but I can think of how to do it!

```
while(keepSpinning){

    turntable = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.deck1);     

    RotateAnimation r ; // = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO);
    r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    r.setDuration(5000);
    r.setRepeatCount(0); 

    turntable.startAnimation(r);
    turntable.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            keepSpinning = false;
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: cant you just cancel the animation in `onTouch()`? `turntable.getAnimation().cancel()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `while(keepSpinning)` loop, [register an AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener%28android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener%29) with the `RotateAnimation`.  The `RotateAnimation` will invoke [onAnimationRepeat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationRepeat%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) on your listener for each loop of the animation, and you can cancel the animation there.